# Accessing parent Template from within {{#each}} blocks

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

In my code, I do the following:

```html
<template name=A>
  {{#if something}}
    {{#each items}}
       {{> items}}
   {{/each}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Elsewhere I need to get the instance of the parent template (A) but using `template.view.parentView` returns template names "each", one level above "if", etc. Is there a way how to get the actual template without iterating and comparing the names?

The parentView returns everything in the chain, but I obviously need the actual templates.

Comment: What exactly in the parent template are you trying to access? Could you pass it as a variable to your child template?

Comment: @KyleBachan I need the parent template to store references to all its children. For that, the child template would need to access the parent field on its onCreated event and add itself to it. If I pass the reference in the template inclusion, I lose the context provided by #each.